# Why document.getElementById() returns null after call a function recursively in angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, recursion, components

I'm using angular 4 and in my component, I have a function that set an HTML element innerHTML. he first time that I do it, it works but the second time it shows `Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null` error! whats the problem?

here is the component:

```
    showOutgingViewForm(id) {
        this.router.navigate(['viewoutgoing/' + id]);
        this.show(id);
      }

    show(id) {
        // setting the style of mail content
        document.getElementById('inner-section').innerHTML = this.toFarsiNumberContect(mail.mail.rows[0].content);
  }
```

and this is html:

```
<md-tab>
   <div class="inner data_font" id="inner-section"></div>
</md-tab>
<md-tab>
   <ng-template let-value="value" let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
     <a class="data_font" (click)="showOutgingViewForm(row.id)">{{value}}</a>
   </ng-template>
</md-tab>
```

Comment: Show your HTML code too

Comment: @PardeepJainI did it now! can you check it?

Comment: `<div class="inner data_font" id="inner-section" [innerHTML] = "toFarsiNumberContect(mail.mail.rows[0].content)"></div>` try this

Comment: @PardeepJain it's not working! it says cannot set mail of undefined! what should i do in my component?

Comment: you need to pass valid params offcourse

Comment: @PardeepJain not working! I think it will be ok if I run my component again!! it just calls the function but not the HTML template!